# Different style for the current link when I clicked

Tags: javascript, css, href

Can anybody help me with my code? I want to put different style of the current link, that I had selected. The hyperlinks do not go to different pages, they all refers to the current page.

here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<nav id="nav">
<ul>
<li class="current"><a href="#top" id="top-link" ><span>Home</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#portfolio" id="portfolio-link"><span>Portfolio</span></a></li>
<li><a href="#about" id="about-link"><span>About</span></a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

**CSS**

```
#nav ul li a:hover
 {
  color:#FFF;
  background-color:#333;
 }

 #nav ul li a:active
 {
 color:#FFF;
 background-color:#333;
 }
```

[FIDDLE DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/yW3Yt/)

Comment: you want to change your styling when someone clicks your link that just goes to an ID? For that you'd need Javascript...

Comment: Dominik is right, on click, you need some scripting to remove the "current" class from your elements, and then add it to the active link element (and of course style the current class)

Comment: yah..how will i do that with javascript? thanks :)

Comment: might be this is you are looking. http://jsbin.com/bosomoga/1/edit

Comment: @kheemaPandey yes..that's what im looking for..thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change the `.current class` on click by using jquery code.

```
var links = $('#nav li');
links.click(function() { 
$(this).parent().find(".current").removeClass('current');
$(this).addClass('current');
 });
```

Check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/bosomoga/5/edit)**.

Comment: if my solution works for you then you may accept this answer.

Comment: This will work, although there is no reason to scan the whole DOM again inside the 'click' function again. you already have the '$(this)' element, and it's much faster to get the 'current' element from there, than to re-search the whole page.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You can't do this with CSS only. You will need some Javascript to achieve that</strike>. (Apparently you can, see edit)

Even though your question isn't tagged jQuery and/or Javascript, here is an example of how to do that using jQuery:

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/yW3Yt/1/***

*Relevant jQuery Code*:

```
$("a").on("click", function() {            // bind click event on all anchors
    $("li").removeClass("current");        // remove current class from all list-items
    $(this).parent().addClass("current");  // add current class to the parent of clicked anchor
});
```

---

### Edit: Apparently, you could have a "CSS only" solution:

The idea is to use hidden radio buttons with corresponding labels. The radio `input`s remain outside the anchors (because inputs are not valid contents for anchors), while labels are wrapped by the anchors.

**Demo 2: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/yW3Yt/4/**

Relevant HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <input type="radio" name="opt" id="opt1"/>
        <a href="#top" id="top-link"><label for="opt1">Home</label></a>
    ...
```

Relevant CSS:

```
input[name="opt"] {
    display: none;
}
input[name="opt"]:checked + a {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, here is the <kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ronency/yW3Yt/2/)</kbd>

I went with:

```
$('li').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('current')
        .siblings().removeClass('current');
});
```